# ItemDataBound slowing my page rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMcVa.png)My first question ever here, forgive if I am not fluent in tech language because I am a self taught developer from deep Africa Mozambique, thanks to this site.

My question is I have a

```
public void topicView_ItemDataBound(object sender,e)
```

In my code behind for a particular aspx page with a repeater, that receives its info from a datatable (if my terminology is correct.) The ItemDataBound event is to  arrange my controls in a repeater for the purpose of hiding, disabling and showing other controls according to the determined criterias. Now I have noticed that the ItemDataBound event is slowing my page load time by some 20 to 40 seconds which is really bad, even on post back. When i remove the ItemDataBound events. I am running smoothly. But i can't work with out the ItemDataBound event since its the only way i know how to arrange a repeater with alternating conditions. Is this a common problem with a quick answer or should i post my full code?? this only happens on 2 pages with this event. I am using c# if thats of any help. net.4.5

```
public void topicView_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            // Show or hid div here
            HiddenField MediaType = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("MediaType");
            HiddenField PageAdmin = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("PageAdmin");
            HiddenField f1 = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("F1");
            HiddenField PP = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("PP");
            HiddenField isread= (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("isread");
            HiddenField tread = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("tread");

            // Label Label2 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label2");
            // Label2.Text = myDDL.Value;
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl image_video = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("image_video");

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl image_pic = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("image_pic");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl PP1 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("PP1");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl userpic = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("userpic");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl compic = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("compic");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl userpic2 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("userpic2");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl compic2 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("compic2");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl pf = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("pf");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl attach = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("attach");

            LinkButton LinkButton3 = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton3");
            LinkButton LinkButton1 = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1");
            Label Label4 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label4");
            Label Label10 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label10");

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image readsign = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Item.FindControl("readsign");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image Image2 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Item.FindControl("Image2");

            if (MediaType.Value == "video")
            {
                image_video.Visible = false;
                image_pic.Visible = true;
                Image2.ImageUrl = "~/images/readmail.png";

            }


            if (MediaType.Value == "image")
            {
                image_video.Visible = true;
                image_pic.Visible = false;

            }

            if (MediaType.Value == "" ) { attach.Visible = false; } else { attach.Visible = true; }

            if (PageAdmin.Value == "False")
            {
                compic.Visible = false;
                userpic.Visible = true;
                userpic2.Visible = true;
                compic2.Visible = false;
            }
            if (PageAdmin.Value == "True")
            {
                userpic.Visible = false;
                compic.Visible = true;
                userpic2.Visible = false;
                compic2.Visible = true;
            }

            if (isread.Value == "True")
            {
                readsign.ImageUrl = "~/images/readmail.png";
                Label4.Text = "foi lido ";
                Label10.Text = tread.Value;
             }
     }

}
```

and my aspx code for the repeater:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
 OnItemDataBound="topicView_ItemDataBound"><ItemTemplate> 
 <div id="messages" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="Status" runat="server" 
 Value='<%#""+Eval("Isreplyed") %>' />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="Pageadmin" runat="server" 
 Value='<%#""+Eval("PageAdmin") %>'/>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="MediaType" runat="server" 
Value='<%#""+Eval("MediaType") %>' />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="isread" runat="server" Value='<%#""+Eval("Isread") 
 %>' />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="tread" runat="server" Value='<%#""+Eval("tread","
 {0:d / MM " + "@" + " HH:mm}") %>' />
    <div id="Omsg" style="padding: 5px; border: thin solid #FFFFFF; box-
 shadow:rgba(255, 255, 255,0.9) 0 0 7px; background-color: #FFFFFF;border-
 radius:5px; " >
 <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-left: 0px;">
  <tr><td colspan="2">
      <asp:Image ID="readsign" runat="server" Height="25" Width="25" 
ImageUrl="~/images/newmail.png" />
      <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# ""+Eval("Isreplyed") 
%>' Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#999999"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%#""+Eval("datesent","{0:d / 
MM " + "@" + " HH:mm}") %>' Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#999999">
</asp:Label>
      </td></tr>         
   <tr>

                <td style="width: 66px; text-align: left;"><a id="pps" ><div 
id="compic" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"><img id="PP1" alt="" 
class="img-rounded" src='<%#"/ProfilePictures/"+Eval("logo") %>' 
style="width: 50px; height: 50px" /></div><input id="Hidden2" type="hidden" 
runat="server" value='<%#"/ProfilePictures/"+Eval("logo") %>' /></a>
                    <div id="userpic" clientidmode="Static" runat="server">

                        <img alt="" class="img-circle" 
src='<%#"/ProfilePictures/"+Eval("ProfilePicture") %>' style="width: 50px; 
height: 50px" />
                    </div><input id="Hidden3" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#"/ProfilePictures/"+Eval("ProfilePicture") %>' />

                     </td>
                <td style="line-height: 15px"> <div id="compic2" 
ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"> <a  href='<%#"/Landing.aspx?
Restid="+Eval("id") %>' ><asp:Label ID="Label2" class="head" runat="server" 
Text='<%# ""+Eval("name") %>' Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="#B9A47B">
</asp:Label> </a><a/><br/>
                      <asp:Label ID="CName" runat="server" 
Text='<%#""+Eval("slogan") %>' Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:Label>.   ...</div>
                     <div id="userpic2" ClientIDMode="Static" 
runat="server"><a  href='<%#"/Landing.aspx?Restid="+Eval("Username") %>' >
<asp:Label ID="Label8" class="head" runat="server" 
Text='<%#""+Eval("Username") %>' Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#B9A47B">
</asp:Label> <a/><br/>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" 
Text='<%#""+Eval("Job") %>' Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:Label></a>
                         <br />
                         <a/>
<a href='<%#"notificationmaster.aspx?BlogId="+Eval("Blogid") %>'> <asp:Label 
ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# "Respondendo à publicação :  
"+Eval("BlogTitle") %>' Font-Size="smaller" ForeColor="#B9A47B"></asp:Label>
</a><br/>


                    </div>
                   <a/><span style="font-size: x-small; color: #999999"> 
enviado : </span><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" 
Text='<%#""+Eval("datesent","{0:d MMMM yyyy - HH:mm}") %>' Font-Size="X-
Small" ForeColor="#999999"></asp:Label></a>
                    <br />
                   <div id="attach" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" > 
<asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="Esta mensagem tem anexo" 
ForeColor="#999999" Font-Size="X-Small" Font-Underline="True">
</asp:Label>&nbsp; <img alt="" src="images/attach.png" style="width: 20px; 
height: 20px" /></div>
                </td>



            </tr>
  <tr>
 <td colspan="2">
&nbsp;
<br/>
<div id="msgbody" style="display: none">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#""+Eval("mbody") %>'>
</asp:Label><br/>
 <div id="image_pic" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" >
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" 
Value='<%#"/PostImages/"+Eval("image") %>' />
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" class="img-thumbnail" ClientIDMode="Static" 
runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"/PostImages/"+Eval("image") %>' alt="Broken" 
Width="100%" />
           </div>
        <div id="image_video" runat="server" onclick="AddView" >
           <video id="PostVedio" runat="server" controls 
poster="/images/chimoioonline.png" src='<%#"/video/"+Eval("video") %>' 
style="width: 100%">
<source src="demo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="demo.webm" type="video/webm"/>
<source src="demo.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
<source src="demo.ogv" type="video/avi"/>             
<p>Fallback code if video isn't supported</p>/
</video></div></div>

 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right">
          <hr style="padding: 2px; margin: 5px" />

          <div id="deletm" style="display: inline-block">
              <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" 
 value='<%#Eval("id")%>' />
          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CssClass="btn" 
 onclick="pmdelet" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="1px"><img 
 src="/images/delete.png" alt="" style=" height: 15px" />
 </asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
              </div> 
          <div id="sendpm" style="display: inline-block">
              <input id="mido" type="hidden" runat="server" 
 value='<%#Eval("id")%>' />
              <input id="Hidden4" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("BlogId")%>' />
              <input id="sender2" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("sender")%>' />
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="btn" 
BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="1px" OnClientClick="" 
PostBackUrl='<%#"PMS.aspx?id=" + Eval("id") + "&BlogId=" + Eval("BlogId")+ 
"&sender=" + Eval("sender")%>' ><img src="images/pvtemail.png" alt="" 
style=" height: 15px" /></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </div>
          <div id="read" style="display: inline-block">
              <input id="H5" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("id")%>' />
              <input id="H7" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#"/ProfilePictures/"+Eval("logo") %>' />
              <input id="H8" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#"/ProfilePictures/"+Eval("ProfilePicture") %>' />
              <input id="H6" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("Isreplyed")%>' />
              <input id="H14" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("Username")%>' />
              <input id="H10" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("name")%>' />
              <input id="H13" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("Subject")%>' />
              <input id="H9" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("BlogTitle")%>' />
              <input id="H11" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("datesent","{0:d / MM " + "@" + " HH:mm}")%>' />
              <input id="H12" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("mbody")%>' />
              <input id="v5" type="hidden" runat="server" value='<%# 
Eval("video")%>' />
              <input id="p5" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("image")%>' />
               <input id="sender" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("sender")%>' />
               <input id="Hidden5" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("Blogid")%>' />
               <input id="PageAdmin2" type="hidden" runat="server" 
value='<%#Eval("PageAdmin")%>' />
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CssClass="btn"  
BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="1px" OnClientClick="return false"><img 
src="/images/read2.png" alt="" style=" height:15px" /></asp:LinkButton>

          </div>

      </td>
  </tr>
            </table>
     </div>

    <div id="Rmsg">

    </div>


</div>
</ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

[My Server profiler screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC3cA.png)

Comment: You will have to share a little bit of your code so we can help you out

Comment: You _might_ have a condition where the code in your itemDataBound Event does a SQL server call for each time it's called. Open up SQL server profiler and check if there are lots of DB hits when you debug the itemDataBound Event. If this is the case, try to cache the entire result from the DB

Comment: @devzero i am very very newbie i didn't get a word of your comment, if you place it in simpler english i can try what ever you said i should do.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but more a way for you to delve deeper into whats the problem. (And it's to long for a comment)

First of all you need to make sure you have SQL server managment tools installed, in particular you need the tool called SQL server profiler.

In profiler you go to "file" "new trace" and connect to you SQL server.

In the Trace properties you select only "RPC:completed" and "SQL:BatchCompleted".

Now you can run your aspx page, and you should se all SQL queries generated by the page in the profiler. There are two things you should look out for.

First of all, look for long running queries. The duration column is in MS and you should not have anyone longer than 1000ms.

Secondly, the number of queries run when the page is run. A normal page should not exceed 20 queries. Usualy when you get problems with this, you could run hundreds.

Comment: I struggling to use the forums formates. but i uploaded the results of the  Server profiler you will see in the first line of my question a link to the image  "enter image description here".. sorry still very new

Comment: The SQL server profiler only shows 2 queries, FeedsCount_SP and Feeds_SP beeing run, and total time for those is 8 ms, so your problem does not lie in the data code. Have you tried to debug your code? If you'r seeing a slowdown of 20s in the topicView_ItemDataBound event, it's either called and insane amount of times, or some line in it takes >1 s to run. Both of these scenarios should be easy to spot while stepping through your code. IF you don't spot it this way, try a performance profiler.

Comment: Ok thanks @devzero taking next step now ,  learning to step through code maybe you can give me heads up how that is done??

Comment: That deepends on your setup, but if you'r running it from visual studio. Start by setting a breakpoint at the first line of the on databound event. Press F5 to start debuging. Run the page and when the breakpoint is hit, you step through with F10.

Comment: Don't give up on me I am still working on your suggestions