# Adding bool ActiveFlag Breaks queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, model

I have a Linq query that pulls a list from my database.  Now I needed to update the model with an ActiveFlag. I ran my migrations to add it to the database. Now, ever since that was added my queries return my primary key in searches (which is a Guid) but nothing else; every other field is returned as null, false, or 0, depending on the default for that field type.  This is really strange.

Here is the LINQ query:

```
var Model =
     from x in db.MinimumProductInfo
     where x != null
     where x.ActiveFlag == active
     select new ProductInfoWithNoteList
     {
          MinimumProductInfoID = x.MinimumProductInfoID,
          ItemCode = x.ItemCode,
          MinimumOnHandQuantity = x.MinimumOnHandQuantity,
          MaximumOHandQuantity = x.MaximumOHandQuantity,
          MinimumOrderQuantity = x.MinimumOrderQuantity,
          LeadTimeInWeeks = x.LeadTimeInWeeks
      };
```

active is passed in and can only be true or false, as it is a bool type.  I thought maybe it was that, so I did a very basic query like this:

```
var test = db.MinimumProductInfo;
```

and I am getting the same result.  However, if I go in my database I see the data.  Is ActiveFlag a keyword or something else that is breaking my database queries?

Comment: Have you tried using SQL server profiler to se what actuall SQL query is generated?

Comment: I did that once at my previous job, I forgot all about it.  I need to remember how to do that.  Let me look it up.

Comment: I wrote a short description on how here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948402/itemdatabound-slowing-my-page-rendering/45954593#comment78994112_45954593

Comment: Which EF version is this?

Comment: @GertArnold 6.1.3